# Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly

Tags: c#, .net

Everytime I build my solution, I get this error message:

> Warning
>
> 3
>
> Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the
>   assembly "StandardClassLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on
>   disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get
>   compilation errors.
>
> StandardClassLibrary

So my application has a number of projects of which `StandardClassLibrary` is one. The above message is a warning and as far as I can tell it does NOT have an impact on my solution.

But I would rather it not be there, just in case...

Comment: write a test that will test the functionality of the methods in the assembly.  run that test on start up and make sure all results are expected, just to be sure (instead of as far as you can tell).

Comment: In VS2019, in project reference, removing the items in yellow flags and reinstalling them from NuGet package manager helped solving this issue.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You most likely get this message when the project points to an old location of the assembly where it no longer exists. Since you were able to build it once, the assembly has already been copied into your `bin\Debug` / `bin\Release` folders so your project can still find a copy.

If you open the references node of the project in your solution explorer, there should be a yellow icon next to the reference. Remove the reference and add it again from the correct location.

If you want to know the location it was referenced from, you'd have to open the .csproj file in a text editor and look for the `HintPath` for that assembly - the IDE for some reason does not show this information.

Comment: Thank you for that. I checked my references and they are all fine, no yellow icons.

Comment: thank you it works ! I had not yellow icon at references but i copied all dlls from debug folder to release folder and it works now.

Comment: I had the yellow triangle but wasn't clear why, your answer helped me finding that it was looking for the wrong version in the locatin

Answer (score 33):

If anyone face this issue with some **nuget** packages, you can fix that by reinstalling the packages using the Package Manager Console:

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

Answer (score 7):

If you have built an image with Docker, and you're getting these strange messages:

> warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate
>   the assembly "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions". Check
>   to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is
>   required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
>   [/src/Utilities/Utilities.csproj]

Open the affected project`Utilities/Utilities.csproj`, (You shall look for your project). You may need to choose Unload Project from the menu first.  Right click on the .csproj file  and edit it.

Now, **delete all the `<HintPath>` tags**

Save, and try again.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

in 2020, this behavior still present with VS2019.
(even if I clean projects from the solution explorer in VS2019, this not solves the problem)

**The solution that worked for me** was to open the folder of the project, and manually remove the \bin and \obj directories.

Comment: I had this problem with a new workstation, fresh install of 16.11.16. Files were in the hint paths as expected but no luck. This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

Check if your project files are read-only. Remove the read-only property by right clicking on the project folder and select properties. In the properties screen remove the read-only checkbox. I came across the same problem, and this solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

If the project is check out to different PC through team foundation server with different location of same library file, there will be no yellow icon mark in Reference but when change to Release build and build the project, it will give an error. Just like what `@C.Evenhuis` said, it will use back old one in previous build (eg: Debug build) so I didn't notice the mistake.

Now I know it is a bad habit to put library files in different location on different PC.

Just need to delete the reference and re-add the same reference from correct location.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same warning in VS 2017. As it turned out in my case I had added a unit test project and needed to set a dependency for the unit test on the DLL it was testing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will help someone, but sometimes Name tag might be missing for a reference and it leads that assembly cannot be found when building with MSBuild.
Make sure that `Name` tag is available for particular reference csproj file, for example,

```
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyDependency1.csproj">
      <Project>{9A2D95B3-63B0-4D53-91F1-5EFB99B22FE8}</Project>
      <Name>MyDependency1</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue after VS mac updation. iOS sdk was  updated. I was referring the ios dll in project folder. The version number in the `hintpath` was changed.

Earlier:

```
<Reference Include="Xamarin.iOS">   
     <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Library\Frameworks\Xamarin.iOS.framework\Versions\13.18.2.1\lib\mono\Xamarin.iOS\Xamarin.iOS.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.iOS">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Library\Frameworks\Xamarin.iOS.framework\Versions\13.18.1.31\lib\mono\Xamarin.iOS\Xamarin.iOS.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.iOS">          <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Library\Frameworks\Xamarin.iOS.framework\Versions\13.18.3.2\lib\mono\Xamarin.iOS\Xamarin.iOS.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

I referred to the numbers in the previous commit and changed only the numbers in project folder, did nothing in android,ios folders. Worked for me!!!

Now:

```
<Reference Include="Xamarin.iOS">                                                            
 <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Library\Frameworks\Xamarin.iOS.framework\Versions\13.20.2.2\lib\mono\Xamarin.iOS\Xamarin.iOS.dll</HintPath>
        </Reference>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had the following warnings:

> Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "x". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

> No way to resolve conflict between "x, Version=1.0.0.248, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" and "x". Choosing "x, Version=1.0.0.248

The path to the dll was correct in my .csproj file but I had it referenced twice and the second reference was with another version. Once I deleted the unnecessary reference, the warning disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

This confused me for a while until I worked out that the dependencies of the various projects in the solution had been messed up. Get that straight and naturally your assembly appears in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, it happened because of .net framework version miss match with MySQL connector library. when I updated my .NET version, every thing worked smooth.
[http://net-informations.com/q/faq/mysql.html#:~:text=Add%20Reference,Library%20in%20your%20C%23%20project](http://net-informations.com/q/faq/mysql.html#:%7E:text=Add%20Reference,Library%20in%20your%20C%23%20project).

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar linker issues while adding a NuGet package into the iOS project (in Xamarin forms project). We had earlier provided the additional mtouch argument in the build configurations like this
*-dlsym:false -cxx  -v -v -v -v -gcc_flags*

After removing *-dlsym:false* from the configuration, the issues got resolved for me.