# C# Referencing two different versions of same assembly

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I need to reference two versions of the same library (Coherence .NET) in my library project and use them both so I've renamed the dll's and referenced them in my project via aliases, however when I try to compile my library I get this warning

```
warning MSB3243: No way to resolve conflict between "Coherence, Version=12.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0ada89708fdf1f9a" and "Coherence, Version=3.3.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0ada89708fdf1f9a". Choosing "Coherence, Version=12.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0ada89708fdf1f9a" arbitrarily
```

And when I try to register my library (it needs to be registered using RegAsm.exe) I get this erorr

```
error MSB3217: Cannot register assembly "C:\Program Files\******.dll". Could not load file or assembly 'Coherence, Version=3.3.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0ada89708fdf1f9a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified
```

Two assembly dll's that I've referenced are Coherence.v3.3.dll and Coherence.v12.1.dll

I've tried adding this to my library's App.config but it didn't solved the problem as I'm still getting same error

```
  <runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Coherence" publicKeyToken="0ada89708fdf1f9a" culture="neutral" />
    <codeBase version="3.3.0.2" href="Coherence.v3.3.dll"/>
    <codeBase version="12.1.2.0" href="Coherence.v12.1.dll"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
 </runtime>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need a way to reference 2 different versions of the same 3rd party DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550981/need-a-way-to-reference-2-different-versions-of-the-same-3rd-party-dll)

Answer (score 0):

As variant, you can create 2 "proxy" assemblies, for each library version.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the project file `.csproj` and make sure `HintPath` is present and `SpecificVersion=True`.

```
<Reference Include="Coherence, Version=12.1.2.0, ...">
  <HintPath>..\references\******.dll</HintPath>
  <SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion>
</Reference>
```

After that you save the file and again rebuild it.

Comment: When I do that it says warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Coherence.v12.1, Version=12.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0ada89708fdf1f9a, processorArchitecture=MSIL".

Comment: For the warning `MSB3245`, you can try C.Evenhuis's answer in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261412/could-not-resolve-this-reference-could-not-locate-the-assembly

Comment: his advice doesn't change the fact that when I change to Specific version = true I get yellow icons next to Coherence references and it still says that it can't resolve the dependencies