# Getting errors during build process in DOT NET CORE 2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, buildmaster

This is my first application with DOT NET CORE 2.0, and it's time to release it in testing server. The application is working fine on local, and I am able to give build on local system on IIS, but I am getting errors when I am trying to give build through Buildmaster or Jenkins.

```
2017-10-16T14:21:12.0143770Z C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1987,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [d:\a\1\s\ChecklistTrainingTracking.Data\ChecklistTrainingTracking.Data.csproj]
2017-10-16T14:21:12.0233989Z C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1987,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [d:\a\1\s\ChecklistTrainingTracking.Data\ChecklistTrainingTracking.Data.csproj]
2017-10-16T14:21:13.8326218Z ConfigureRepositoryCollection.cs(3,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Extensions' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\ChecklistTrainingTracking.Data\ChecklistTrainingTracking.Data.csproj]
2017-10-16T14:21:13.8326218Z ConfigureRepositoryCollection.cs(4,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Extensions' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\ChecklistTrainingTracking.Data\ChecklistTrainingTracking.Data.csproj]
2017-10-16T14:21:13.8326218Z ConfigureRepositoryCollection.cs(5,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Extensions' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\ChecklistTrainingTracking.Data\ChecklistTrainingTracking.Data.csproj]
2017-10-16T14:21:13.8346216Z Repository\ChecklistRepository.cs(8,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Extensions' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\ChecklistTrainingTracking.Data\ChecklistTrainingTracking.Data.csproj]
2017-10-16T14:21:13.8346216Z Repository\ReportRepository.cs(2,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Extensions' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\ChecklistTrainingTracking.Data\ChecklistTrainingTracking.Data.csproj]
2017-10-16T14:21:13.8346216Z ConfigureRepositoryCollection.cs(14,75): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IServiceCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\ChecklistTrainingTracking.Data\ChecklistTrainingTracking.Data.csproj]
2017-10-16T14:21:13.8346216Z ConfigureRepositoryCollection.cs(14,104): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IConfiguration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\ChecklistTrainingTracking.Data\ChecklistTrainingTracking.Data.csproj]
2017-10-16T14:21:13.8346216Z ConfigureRepositoryCollection.cs(14,23): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IServiceCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\ChecklistTrainingTracking.Data\ChecklistTrainingTracking.Data.csproj]
2017-10-16T14:21:13.8356414Z Repository\ChecklistRepository.cs(17,9): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IConfiguration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\ChecklistTrainingTracking.Data\ChecklistTrainingTracking.Data.csproj]
2017-10-16T14:21:13.8356414Z Repository\ChecklistRepository.cs(18,36): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IConfiguration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\ChecklistTrainingTracking.Data\ChecklistTrainingTracking.Data.csproj]
2017-10-16T14:21:13.8356414Z Repository\ReportRepository.cs(17,9): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IConfiguration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\ChecklistTrainingTracking.Data\ChecklistTrainingTracking.Data.csproj]
2017-10-16T14:21:13.8356414Z Repository\ReportRepository.cs(18,33): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IConfiguration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\ChecklistTrainingTracking.Data\ChecklistTrainingTracking.Data.csproj]
2017-10-16T14:21:13.9166247Z ##[error]Error: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe failed with return code: 1
2017-10-16T14:21:13.9166247Z ##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : d:\a\1\s\ChecklistTraningTracking.sln
```

I am two projects in my solution. Web project don't have any errors, but Data project have.
I have below libraries in my solution,

[image: DLL's available]

Do I need to add any packages or other libraries?

Comment: I had the similar problem, I updated to the latest version of visual studio, and it solved the problem, visual studio 2017 update 4, with update 3 I was getting errors like this.

Comment: I already have visual studio 2017 version 15.4.0

Comment: try this - [old assembly location ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14261692/4571681)

Comment: @KevalPatel can you share the contents of the  `ChecklistTrainingTracking.Data.csproj` file?