# MSBuild error: "Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly..."

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I am aware that there is already a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261412/could-not-resolve-this-reference-could-not-locate-the-assembly) asking about the exact same error message, but unfortunately the accepted answer doesn't work for me.

I was able to build my current solution successfully earlier this morning, but the build suddenly started failing ~15 minutes ago, with the following error message:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5):
>   warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate
>   the assembly "MyAssembly.dll". Check to make sure the assembly exists
>   on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get
>   compilation errors.

Unfortunately for me, this DLL is required by my code. Because it cannot be located, my solution won't compile.

I have tried cleaning and then building my solution again, but that was useless.

I noticed that there was a yellow icon next to this reference, so I removed the reference and then added it again from the exact same location specified inside the `<HintPath>` tag in my `.csproj` file. (The location was the `\bin\Debug` folder.) The yellow icon then disappeared.

However, **immediately** after I clicked on "Build solution" (in `Debug` mode), the yellow icon appeared again, and once more I saw the same MSBuild error message, informing me that the DLL could not be located.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a project reference to the `MyAssembly` project, not a reference to the compiled output. Right click on the References node of the project which needs `MyAssembly.dll`, go to "Add Reference", then choose "Solution":

[image: Solution reference]

---

Say you have two projects (X and Y) with Y depending on X. Visual Studio will build X first, then Y.

You can add a reference to X in Y in one of two ways:

- Reference the project in the solution
- Reference the compiled output in the `\bin\Debug` folder

If the reference is to the project in the solution, then Visual Studio will know which order to compile your projects (X, then Y in our example).

If the reference is to the output in `\bin\Debug`, then Visual Studio won't know which order to compile the assemblies, and could try to compile Y before X, not find the file in `\bin\Debug`, and not compile.

Comment: My issue was buried 3 levels deep.  This answer helped me find it.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, different solution:

My Solution consists of a dll project and an exe test project.
VS changed the startup project to the dll somehow.
Right-Click on your Solution,
Choose properties,
Examine the Startup Project and Project Dependencies settings.