# Azure function publish fails - can't find any files referenced in dependent project CS0246

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a function that depends on code in another project within the solution.
[image: screenshot]

It builds locally, and runs succesfully locally. But when I try to publish, I get errors for every single file that I reference in the other project. How do I publish correctly in this scenario. My csproj file for the function app includes project references for all nuget packages and the project the function depends on.

Comment: Could you verify your VS version? Use the latest version avoid trouble, right now is VS2017 15.9.3.

Comment: Ah, i'm on an older version:  VS2017 15.8.28010.20003. I will update and try again.

Comment: Ok I still having the same issue after updating VS2017 to 15.9.3. The build process during publishing is failing. "Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly '...' "   these are assemblies that the dependent project uses. Shoud I try adding all of these assemblies to the assemblies folder of my azure function project?

Comment: Probably don't have to, the problem may be related to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261412/could-not-resolve-this-reference-could-not-locate-the-assembly).