# .NET Maui: I can not debug in iOS because of "Could not load file or assembly Xamarin.HotReload.Contracts.dll" message

Tags: .net-6.0, .net-maui

when I try to debug my mobile application in iOS mobile I get the following error message that prevent lunching the application

- It work fine in Android mobile (Debug & Deploy)
- I can deploy the application to iOS mobile and it is running without any issue

***the problem only when I try to debug in iOS mobile !!***

```
    2022-09-21 22:36:48.986 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[7534:887994] Could not resolve assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract, Version=17.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. Details: Could not load file or assembly '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9E6C6404-A165-49B0-9748-DC6534494814/Documents/MyMobileApp.content/Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract.dll' or one of its dependencies.
    
    2022-09-21 22:36:48.990 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[7534:887994] Could not resolve assembly Xamarin.HotReload.Contracts, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. Details: Could not load file or assembly '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9E6C6404-A165-49B0-9748-DC6534494814/Documents/MyMobileApp.content/Xamarin.HotReload.Contracts.dll' or one of its dependencies.
    
    Resolved pending breakpoint for 'Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadAgent.BreakpointSendToIde(System.String)' to D:\a\_work\1\s\HotReload\Source\Xamarin.HotReload.Agent\HotReloadAgent.cs:419 [0x00000].
    **System.IO.FileNotFoundException:** 'Could not load file or assembly '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9E6C6404-A165-49B0-9748-DC6534494814/Documents/MyMobileApp.content/Xamarin.HotReload.Contracts.dll' or one of its dependencies.'
    
    The app has been terminated.
```

Comment: Can you tell me the version number of vs used?

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT  I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Version 17.3.3

Comment: I just update to Version 17.3.4 , and still getting the same problem

Comment: This issue can help you.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261412/could-not-resolve-this-reference-could-not-locate-the-assembly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue fixed after removing the `Visual Studio 17.4 preview` and reinstall the stable release

Answer (score 0):

Could not resolve assembly Xamarin.HotReload.Contracts, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. Details: Could not load file or assembly

now version 17.7.4 this issue alway saved